# pass values from drop-down list to textbox in same form using php

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to add value to textbox from drop down list in same form. Here is my code:

```
<tr>
    <td>
    <?php
    require_once '../componetsUsed/dbconfig.php';
    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM artist ORDER BY art_id DESC");
    $stmt->execute();
    ?>
        <select name='art_id' class='form-control' required>
            <option disabled selected>Select Artist</option>    
            <?php
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['art_id']; ?>"><?php echo ucwords(strtolower($row['art_name'])); ?></option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <input type='text' name='art_name' class='form-control' value=""/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to add selected option (Artist Name) to inputbox. (I can fetch data to select menu from database). How can I do that without using JavaScript?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Without using scripts? What kind of scripts do you not want to use? You have to use something. You mean no JavaScript?

Comment: @Rasclatt I mean javascript and jquery. Let me know can't do it without them?

Comment: Yes you can, but you have to submit the form and do some logic in order for it to work. Javascript is way easier to implement in that regards

Comment: @Rasclatt can you please let me know the solution?

Comment: What kind of solution? Javascript or no Javascript?

Comment: Can do it without javascript, Please let me know it.

Comment: Yes, you can do it without javascript, you have to have an action like `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="art_name" />`. Then if you submit the form, you check for the action and populate the text field. It's hard to fully explain. But, that being said, it's not very user-friendly in comparison to js

Comment: @Rasclatt Thank you very much for your answer. I'll check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#drp_dwn").change(function () {
    $("#textArea").val(this.value);
 }).change();
```

check this demo also http://jsfiddle.net/TZQnS/234/